# Inherit class minus some fields - possible workarounds?

Tags: c#, inheritance

I don't have access to the definition of a class but I can inherit from it. I want in the derived class to be denied from accessing some fields that are public in the base class for obvious reasons of accidentally accessing/setting/getting the fields/properties.
What choices do I have?
EDIT:
Why the downvote? I have to refactor a large code that was using the said inherited fields and I have to manually treat the lines involving not only those but also the chained inherited fields down the hierarchical tree.
Additionally I have to make sure even I or my partners won't access those fields/properties and still using those intentedly inherited.
EDIT:
A distinction must be made between 2 separate cases: when the programmer designs the application from ground up and when s/he is compelled to proceed from inaccessible code.
In the former case s/he is responsible for applying OOP and design patterns as best fit for the future intended use s/he envisions.
In the latter, situations often come up when the programmer needs to develop from a slightly modified *proprietary* given class to avoid unneeded complications for the long term. Often times the original code designer can't exhaust the use cases. Thus the developer makes a custom version of the class with the "promise" the original class *won't be used* and even if ever used, it will only be used for the purposes originally intended, and *no inheritance or other relation exists with the new version*. This new version would have additional members and other missing members as compared to the original class. This would be consistent with I in SOLID, albeit adapted for classes.
In these cases I admit that inheritance is not the way to go, as it has a different purpose and the developer would break L (and conceptually I) from SOLID by using inheritance. But there's no feature of any language that provides for this, so there's no choice left.

Comment: This is impossible "for obvious reasons" of that's not how inheritance works. If you aren't inheriting the entire interface, then you are not using inheritance. You want something else. Have you considered composition? It is generally to be preferred over inheritance anyway.

Comment: An alternate suggestion to @jailmetotal 's answer would be to create an interface that only exposes your desired properties/methods, instead of all inherited. This, of course, means that you'll have to stick to referencing the object as an interface, and never the instance class.

Comment: @CodyGray: I'm using 90% of the base class and I can't see how not to inherit from it. How could I use composition?

Comment: @BjarkeSøgaard: I have loads of code relying on the base class that I want to go on using on the inherited class. I can't foresee the magnitude of refactoring.

Comment: @mireazma Yep, then you'll robably want to go with jaimetotal's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, you need to use the Decorator/Wrapper design pattern. Instead of inherinting it, you wrap a class around it.

The class you have:

```
public class SealedPerson
{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public string Prop2 {get;set;}
}
```

The class you need:

```
public class SealedPersonWrapper
{
    public SealedPersonWrapper(SealedPerson person)
    {
        this.Prop1 = person.Prop1;
    }

    public string Prop1 {get; private set;}
}
```

Comment: this implies that I get through all the wanted inherited fields and re-write them, which I'm considering, though it's a lot of code.

Comment: @mireazma What I usually do is go to Notepad++, regex on a copy of base class and wrap it in the new class. Depending on how much properties you have, it can be quicker. And it's more entertaining.

Comment: I need total access interdiction to `Prop1` and I can't make both accessors private.

Comment: @mireazma In those cases, you just remove them?

Comment: Thank you jaimetotal but I don't know if I got it: **1.** In `SealedPersonWrapper` c-tor I make all the "passes" for the members that I want to exist in the new class. And for those I want "deleted" it suffices to just omit them. **2.** Could I make a trick through implicit cast or delegates so that whenever a 3rd party code does `person.Prop4` the compiler does instead `new SealedPersonWrapper(person).Prop4`? **3.** How can I know more of the regex and Notepad++ method? I'm clueless. Please let me know.

Comment: **1.** You can pass the object instead of a group of members. I think is cleaner and is SealedPersonWrapper's responsability to know which properties to show.
**2.** Can you ellaborate on that? It made me confused.
**3.** What I usually do is a find/replace with notepad++.

Comment: Thanks for your patience. **2.** I wasn't clear I know. What I meant was: I don't think I could use 3rd party libs with a `SealedPersonWrapper` `person` since they expect a `SealedPerson` or derived type.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by separating interfaces:

```
public class BaseClass:IBase
{
     private int A;
     private int B;
     void IBase.SetA()
     {
          A=10;
     }
     public void SetB()
     {
          B=10;
     }
}

public class DerivedClass:BaseClass
{
    public Set()
    {
          base.SetB();
          //method SetA will not accessible through base class, but will accessible with IBase interface
    }
}
```

Comment: `public void IBase.SetA()` ('the modifier public is not valid for this item')(SetA). Without public: `IBase in explicit interface declaration is not an interface`

Comment: Anyway, I'm interested in your solution because it's way much easier to write code especially for the unwanted fields than for the wanted ones, since using 90% of the base class.

Comment: As I told you: Without public: `IBase in explicit interface declaration is not an interface`. Plus what do I do with properties? The variables I'm trying to get rid of are properties in the inaccessible class. I tried to adapt but I was unsuccessful.

Comment: @mileazma Sure you should define IBase interface..... Explicit interface declaration works with properties same like with methods. Here you can find more info - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/64syzecx(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you sir for your patience. If I understand correctly, I will not be able to access an inherited property B directly, I'm forced to use an accessor? Further, following the case stated by @jaimetotal `Base base = new Derived(); base.A=0;` unfortunately worked. I tried to hide property A with `int IBase.A {get; set;}` but as I said, I can still access `base.A`.

Answer (score 0):

Hide the inherited fields/properties/methods that you want unusable and make so using them would generate an error, like so:

```
public class Base // not owned code
{
   public int free {get; set;};
   public int limited {get; set;};
} 

public class Derived:Base // owned code
{
   // public new int limited; // NOT hidden! Still accessing Base.limited!

   // working:
   [Obsolete("Inaccessible hidden inherited variable", true)]
   public new int limited {get; set;}  
}
```

`true` is necessary to prohibit the compilation (trigger an error) instead of compiling with warning.
It's way much easier to write code especially for the unwanted fields than for the wanted ones, since using 90% of the base class.

Comment: That won't solve the issue totally because you are using the `new` keyword.
You can't use like this:
`var derived = new Derived();
derived.limited=0;`

But you can use like this:
`Base base = new Derived();
base.limited=0;`

Since `new` hides the implementation of the base class but if the variable type is the base class, `new` doesn't work.

Comment: @jaimetotal: I can't believe I missed that. You are right.